# How to populate Zookeeper service with properties

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign

I have an spring application. It uses zookeeper to manage cluster access. I want populate zookeeper service with properties data to dynamic reconfigure spring beans.

How I can put properties into zookeeper service?
Can I populate data using spring for that?
Can I have an example or spring class names to investigate and be able solve my problem please?

Comment: Refer this [Spring-Zookeeper](https://github.com/james-wu-shanghai/spring-zookeeper)

Comment: @Sagar, thank you for your help, but it seems does not help me, sorry. Possible you knows some classes (factories\bridges) from spring-cloud-feign to resolve my issue in easiest way....

Comment: Seems I have got quit good [spring cloud documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-zookeeper/spring-cloud-zookeeper.html). I hope it will solve my problem. I'll add the answer if no one ahead of me.

Comment: Rather than using ZooKeeper client directly, it is better if you can use `Apache Curator` instead which is a improved client written on top of zookeeper client. If you use that, you can solve those problems easily